# Angular5-Ngx-pagination:Check first page or last page

Tags: javascript, pagination, angular5

I've implemented the pagination using http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/

```
 <pagination-controls  (pageChange)="updatesPageChanged($event)"  previousLabel="" nextLabel="" id="updates"></pagination-controls>

<div class="cards" *ngFor="let item of completedDeals | paginate: {id:'updates', itemsPerPage:limit, currentPage:currentPage,totalItems:totalItems}">

</div>
```

This works fine, however, I need to check current pagination is in first or last page

> From the documentation i can use the following functions isFirstPage()
>   [() => boolean] Returns true if the current page is the first page.
>   isLastPage() [() => boolean] Returns true if the current page is the
>   last page getLastPage() [() => number] Returns the page number of the
>   last page.

But i don't how those functions use with `pagination-controls`

Comment: your question is, you dont know what is the use of isLastPage();

Comment: Please read my question `need to check current pagination is in first or last page`

Comment: create a custom component as explained in the documentation, it will be easy

Comment: So there is no other way except the custom component??

Comment: this is how you declare in component, right ?
export class MyComponent {
    p: number = 1;
    collection: any[] = someArrayOfThings;  
}

Comment: you have the page number 'p' in your component, check value of 'p', if it is 1 => first page, 'p' => your_array.length, then last page :D